# ASP.NET Core BackgroundService hang up application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I need a Background Service that will be executed with a certain frequency. Also I need to be able to wake up this service. For this I use `BackgroundService` and `AutoResetEvent`. The complete code is as follows

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WakeUpService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<CustomBackgroundService>();
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/WakeUp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<WakeUpService>().WakeUp();
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("WakeUp: " + DateTime.Now);
    });
});
app.MapWhen(_ => true, appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.Run(async context => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("OK: " + DateTime.Now); });
});
app.Run();

public class CustomBackgroundService(WakeUpService wakeUpService) : BackgroundService
{
    private int _counter;
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await InternalWorkAsync();
            wakeUpService.Delay();
        }
    }

    private Task InternalWorkAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Counter: " + _counter++);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class WakeUpService
{
    private AutoResetEvent ResetEvent { get; } = new(false);
    public void WakeUp() => ResetEvent.Set();
    public void Delay() => ResetEvent.WaitOne(3000);
}
```

The problem is that although the service itself starts and works, the endpoints (/WakeUp or any other) do not work. But if I wrap `ExecuteAsync` in `Task.Run` everything starts working.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await InternalWorkAsync();
            wakeUpService.Delay();
        }
    });
}
```

Why does this happen and how reliable is the approach with `Task.Run`?

**Update**

As far as I understand, this all happens because the framework starts the service as follows

```
public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Create linked token to allow cancelling executing task from provided token
    _stoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

    // Store the task we're executing
    _executeTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

    // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
    if (_executeTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _executeTask;
    }

    // Otherwise it's running
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And then, most likely, `await service.StartAsync(token)`. Therefore, if you return an IsCompleted task to it, the framework will wait for `_executeTask` and will wait for it until the first `await` occurs in it. Therefore the following code

```
private async Task InternalWorkAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Counter: " + _counter++);
    if (_counter > 3)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

will start running after `_counter` becomes greater than `3`. I modify my code as follows

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await InternalWorkAsync();
        wakeUpService.Delay();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the links to similar questions that helped me understand more about what's going on.

Comment: `InternalWorkAsync` is not "truly async". If you need to simulate async work use `Task.Delay` or in some cases `Task.Yield`.

Comment: Yes, but in real code, an asynchronous operation happens depending on conditions, and if it does not happen, the program hangs until it happens.

Comment: Yes, got through the duplicates, it should be covered by them (feel free to upvote questions and answers if you found them useful). `Task.Run` enforces execution on ThreadPool so it will fix the issue but in this case `Task.Yield` should be enough.